# Policing would-be immigrants away from rich countries borders: US vs EU

Tags: united-states, european-union, immigration, comparative-politics, foreign-aid

Apparently the EU has been [increasingly](https://www.dw.com/en/outsourcing-border-controls-to-africa/av-45599271) conditioning funding of various programs in Africa on African countries stopping would-be immigrants to Europe far away from the actual EU borders. I've also read that the US administration has been doing [some of this](https://en.mercopress.com/2019/04/01/trump-cuts-aid-to-central-american-countries-to-stop-immigration-to-the-us) in Latin America.

Are there some comparative figures for the two (US vs EU), e.g. in the following categories:

- direct programs sponsored (in poor/third countries) for stopping would-be immigrants, e.g. programs for  combating human trafficking,
- amount of aid conditioned on stopping would-be immigrants,
- threats of tariffs or other sanctions (I think only the US has [resorted](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-49134544) to these, but I could be wrong).